# Why can't I chat? I have 33 rep; is this an error? How do I fix it?

Tags: bug, chat

I have 33 rep and cannot chat; why? You have to have 20 to do so; is this an error? How do I fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried joining a SE chat room? What message do you get when you try to log into a room?

Comment: I get the message "You must have 20 reputation on Stack Overflow to talk here. See the faq." I now have 51 rep!

Answer (score 3):

There is a delay when synchronizing reputation to chat. With the age of this question, it should be fixed now. However, if it still persists, log in to all other Stack Exchange sites you regularlyuse, and then go to http://chat.stackexchange.com and click the `Log In` link in the top bar of http://chat.stackexchange.com if you are not logged in already. The message you get:

> You must have 20 reputation on Stack Overflow to talk here. See the faq.

is shown to all users entering the site, and will go away after a second, wen it will either log in via StackAuth or otherwise automatically log in.